# Регулярное выражение. Вывести все строки кроме 2-хзначных

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

вывести на экран только строки, не содержащие двузначных чисел.
\d{1}|\d{3,} - так пробовал, еще так ([^\d{2,}] -тут оно выводит только числа 1 значные, но не 3-х значные. И как быть с словами? Хелп)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, такое должно подойти:

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^((?!(^|\D)\d\d(\D|$)).)*$"))
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/QTDu5j

Comment: Думал исправить случай, которые вы привели — в итоге вышла регулярка которая у вас в ответе (разве что `\d\d` заменил бы на `\d{2}` для читабельности, но это мелочь). Поэтому удалил свой ответ. Спасибо огромное за внимательность.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, бывает :) Не за что.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение `[^\d{2,}]` находит 1 любой символ, отличный от цифры, `{`, `2`, `,` и `}`, так как `[^...]` — это исключающий символьный класс.

В этом случае гораздо удобнее пойти от обратного: регулярное выражение должно находить двузначное число, однако результат `Regex.IsMatch` при этом необходимо "реверсировать".

Выражение для двузначных чисел:

```
(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)
```

[См. демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%5Cd%7B2%7D%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%201%0D%0A15%20%D0%90%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%0D%0A%D0%98%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20234%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%0D%0A%D0%98%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%202834%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%0D%0A%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%201%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2012%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20123.)

- `(?<!\d)` - перед двумя цифрами не может быть цифры
- `\d{2}` - две цифры
- `(?!\d)` - за двумя цифрами не может следовать цифра

Пример кода:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)"); // Двузначное число
var textArr = new List<string>() { "Это выведется 1", "15 А это нет", "И это 234 выведется", "И это даже 2834 выведется", "Это 1 выведется 12 хотя не должно 123." };
var filteredArr = textArr.Where(s => !rx.IsMatch(s)); // Результат реверсирован
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", filteredArr));
// => ["Это выведется 1", "И это 234 выведется", "И это даже 2834 выведется"]
```

[См. C# демо](https://ideone.com/3APaoL)

Но если у вас нет возможности изменить код, можно воспользоваться

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d))", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var filteredArr = textArr.Where(s => rx.IsMatch(s));
```

[См. C# демо](https://ideone.com/ZfwwSd)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d))` - исключающий блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который возвращает *False*, если его шаблон находит совпадение:

  - `.*` - любой символ, 0 и более, как можно больше
  - `(?<!\d)` - перед двумя цифрами не может быть цифры
  - `\d{2}` - две цифры
  - `(?!\d)` - за двумя цифрами не может следовать цифра

Answer (score 0):

А числа пробелами всегда отбиваются? Или прям в тек98сте могут быть?

Если не могут то:

```
        var rx = new Regex(@"((\s|^)\d{1}(\s|$))|((\s|^)\d{3,}(\s|$))");
        var textArr = new List<string>()
        {
            "Это выведется 1",
            "15 А это нет",
            "И это 234 выведется",
            "И это даже 2834 выведется"
        };
        var filteredArr =textArr.Where(s => rx.IsMatch(s));
```

Comment: Что-то сложно, лень читать.

Comment: Не читайте =) =)

Comment: Ладно, прочитал. `Это 1 выведется 12 хотя не должно 123.`

Comment: С чего ради?  Не пройдет ни одна строка, где есть двузначные числа, при условии что они отделены пробелом(ами) от текста. .

Comment: Да ну? http://ideone.com/VuvU27

Comment: Упс. Ну так да, хоть такого нет в условии =)